# Где (между какими тегами) может содержаться элемент address?

Tags: html5, теги, структуры, address

Непонятно, где все-таки может содержаться элемент `<address>`? Согласно спецификации HTML5 https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/sections.html#the-article-element

> Contexts in which this element can be used: Where flow content is
>   expected.

Примерный перевод: Между тегами flow content.

Но если читать дальше, написано

> The address element represents the contact information for its nearest
>   article or body element ancestor

Примерный перевод: Элемент `<address>` представляет содержимое ближайшего родительского элемента `<article>` или `<body>`

Поэтому неясно, элемент  может содержаться между `<article>` и `<body>` или между `flow content`, где куча тегов?

Comment: Если он внутри `<article>`, то это контактная информация для данной статьи. Если внутри `<body>` (т.е. вне `<article>`, если они там есть), то для всего документа/страницы.

Comment: Я имел ввиду. Где допускается согласно спецификации, между article и body или flow content?